# ios basic image processing extract red channel

Tags: ios, image-processing, accelerate-framework

straight forward I need to extract color components from an image, usually in Matlab this is done choosing the first matrix for Red.

In the realm of accelerate framework, which documentation is reference-based I can't find an easy way of doing this without resolving to graphics context.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```c
UIImage* image = // An image
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8* pixelBytes = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

//32-bit RGBA
for(int i = 0; i < CFDataGetLength(pixelData); i += 4) {
    pixelBytes[i]   // red
    pixelBytes[i+1] // green
    pixelBytes[i+2] // blue
    pixelBytes[i+3] // alpha
}
```

Comment: @AntonPalich This has nothing to do with the OP's question, but what is the origin of the pixel index?  Does it start at the top/left of the image and is row orientated?

Comment: I will not be able to see the results ( getting pixel values to a filter in the frequency domain ) so if it is not for sure please let me know, or if there is a better way for that matter.

Comment: @Zoidberg Im absolutely sure, that you was right. I have changed code a little. Simple example for manipulating pixels: https://github.com/AntonPalich/ImageBytesExample