# for loops in objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, loops, image-processing

Apologies for a basic question. I have checking out the `for` loops [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265386/1886931) and [here](http://www.fiveminutes.eu/iphone-image-processing/) and for example if we analyse the first code :

```
for(int i = 0; i < CFDataGetLength(pixelData); i += 4) {
    pixelBytes[i]   // red
    pixelBytes[i+1] // green
    pixelBytes[i+2] // blue
    pixelBytes[i+3] // alpha
}
```

The variable `i` is being incremented from 0 to the length of the array `pixelData`, in steps of 4.

However how does `pixelBytes[i+3]` access the alpha channel of the image? So for example if `i=5`, how does `pixelBytes[5+3]` equal the alpha channel instead of just accessing the 8th element of `pixelBytes`?

Comment: i cannot be 5. I takes values like 0, 4, 8, 12 etc. Therefore pixelBytes[5+3] does not access an alpha channel. It corresponds to the red channel of the 3rd pixel or colour or whatever your pixelData represents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have colours stored in the RGBA format. In the RGBA format, one colour is stored in 4 bytes, the first byte being the value for red (R), second is green (G), third is blue (B), and last is alpha (A).

Your own code explains this pretty well in its comments:

```
pixelBytes[i]   // red
pixelBytes[i+1] // green
pixelBytes[i+2] // blue
pixelBytes[i+3] // alpha
```

It is important to note though, that if i is not a multiple of 4, you're not going to be reading the colours correctly anymore.

While the code isn't there, it is likely that pixelBytes is an array of size equal to the total number of colours times 4, which is the same thing as the number of total bytes used to represent the colours (since each colour is stored in 4 bytes)

Answer (score 4):

If `i` starts at zero and is incremented by 4 each time, how can it ever equal 5?

Presumably, the structure is stored with each channel occupying one byte, first red, then green, then blue, then alpha, then red again and so on. The `for` loop mimics this structure by increment `i` by four each time, so if the first time through `pixelBytes[i+1]` is the first green value, the second time through it will be four bytes later and thus the second green value.

Comment: Sorry, that was a very basic mistake. Essentially what I'm trying to ask is how does i being equal to 1 for e.g. correspond to the pixel in green channel (for e.g)? So how is the above loop iterating through the different channels of the image? I am used to the Matlab convention.

Comment: @Hasnain: Except `i` can never be equal to 1. If `i` could be equal to 1, then it wouldn't work at all. The loop iterates through the different channels of the image because `i` is always a multiple of 4 and each channel repeats every four bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes it helps to unrool the loop on a sheet of paper

```
// First pixel
RGBA 
^    Index 0 = i(0) + 0
 ^   Index 1 = i(0) + 1
  ^  Index 2 = i(0) + 2
   ^ Index 3 = i(0) + 3

            i + 4
     // Second pixel
RGBA RGBA      
     ^    Index 4 = i(4) + 0
      ^   Index 5 = i(4) + 1
       ^  Index 6 = i(4) + 2
        ^ Index 7 = i(4) + 3

            i + 4
          // Third pixel
RGBA RGBA RGBA      
          ^    Index 8 = i(8) + 0
           ^   Index 9 = i(8) + 1
            ^  Index 10 = i(8) + 2
             ^ Index 11 = i(8) + 3
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical 32 bit pixel consists of four channels, alpha, red, green and blue. 
My guess is that pixelbytes is a bytebuffer of these, so:

```
pixelbuffer[0] = r
pixelbuffer[1] = g
pixelbuffer[2] = b
pixelbuffer[3] = a
```

as your code says.
On each iteration, it adds four bytes (8 bit * 4 = 32 bit) to the counter, equaling the offset to the next 32bit pixel. The individual components can be accessed through a byte offset (i + <0-3>).