# Extract cyan channel of UIImage?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I was wondering, is it possible to extract the cyan channel of a `UIImage` into a separate `UIImage`? Kind of like how in Photoshop, you can click the tab that says Cyan and it shows the Cyan channel of the image. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

By modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13265386/2770572), you can get something.

```
CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(image.CGImage));
const UInt8* pixelBytes = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);

int cyanChannel = 0;
//32-bit RGBA
for(int i = 0; i < CFDataGetLength(pixelData); i += 4) {
    cyanChannel += pixelBytes[i + 1] + pixelBytes[i + 2]; // cyan = green + blue
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know, is there a way to represent the cyanChannel into a UIImage?